# git repository on server for unrelated multiple projects and multiple users

Tags: git

I'm trying to set up something like the following:

Multiple unrelated projects, each with its own set of users, in a common git server, running Ubuntu.

I know that one conventional solution is simply to assign a group to each project, and add each set of users to that group and so on.  But I have two complicating factors: we have outside collaborators (which I will deal with using ssh) and we have users on our system who have approached a maximum limit on the number of groups they may belong to.

**My primary interest is in ensuring that users A, B, and C have access only to project A; D, E and F only to project B (and so on) and I cannot rely on using unix group membership to do so.**

For our svn repository, we switched to using the authz protocol to get around this problem.  However, I'm starting to have users interested in setting up git repositories for their research projects, so I'm looking for ways to limit sets of users to particular projects without using groups in git.  Is this possible?  I'm actually starting to wonder if I should place each repository in its own account and dump ssh keys into an authorized keys folder :-/

I've spent about an hour browsing through the git questions here (not to mention googling at large), but they all seem to be describing different situations, mostly multiple projects that one person has, or multiple people accessing one project, that kind of thing.  I'm not seeing anything about preventing one set of users from getting into projects they are not assigned to.  (The projects are completely self contained, not part of each other.)

If I've missed an obvious previous answer, do slap me with the obligatory wet noodle (and give me the link?).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could invert to the problem and make the projects belong to one user name..

IE:

```
$> adduser my_project_1
```

Then install ssh keys for each project(aka user) in ~my_project_1/.ssh/authorized_keys

Then someone would gain access via:

```
my_project_1@myserver:git/project.git
```

then you can have my_project_2, _3, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly what you've asked for, but it sounds like what you probably need is some kind of easy (probably web-based) interface for managing and creating Git repositories, like a self-hosted version of Github or Bitbucket.

If this is what you're after, there's a few off-the-shelf options, both FOSS and commercial. I know of [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/gitlab-ce/) and [Gitorious](http://getgitorious.com/) for FOSS solutions, but I haven't used either so can't offer any recommendations as to what they're like.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for **[Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/)**. Gitolite is an 
[access control layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html#what) built on top of Git that gives you the ability to configure the access to repositories at a rather fine scale. Users defined using Gitolite are independent from the system’s users and in fact, all communication is usually done over a single `git` user account.

You can also define groups of users and assign individual rights. It is quite powerful and extensible in case you need to have a *very exotic* case.

Rights are assignable globally for all repositories, a group of repositories, or even individual repositories. You can even allow users to create repositories on their own, for example while enforcing a naming scheme like `<user>/<repo>`.

Gitolite further prevents you from having to hand real SSH access to *anybody*. Of course you can still give some members of your team their own shell access, but the whole Git communication would still run over Gitolite’s user, restricting the access to Git commands and enforcing all of Gitolite’s policies you configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something with a nice interface and fine grained control over user permissions and  is also free. You can try [Git Blit](http://gitblit.com/)

I use it for work and it helps me manage offshore teams across multiple projects.

Here are some screens. I highly recommend it.

[image: Activity]
<sub>(source: [gitblit.com](http://gitblit.com/screenshots/00c.png))</sub>

[image: Repository Control]
<sub>(source: [gitblit.com](http://gitblit.com/screenshots/01c.png))</sub>

[image: Users]
<sub>(source: [gitblit.com](http://gitblit.com/screenshots/01.png))</sub>

[Download it here for Linux](https://web.archive.org/web/20140330100018/http://gitblit.googlecode.com/files/gitblit-1.3.2.tar.gz)